# How to remove an attribute in YAML file using yq?

Tags: docker-compose, yaml, azure-pipelines, yq

Because of a recent change in the `ubuntu-latest` [image](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/issues/1570#issuecomment-690909907) that introduced a buggy version of docker-compose, I had to lock down the version of docker-compose on my pipelines.

However, there was a task that I used to help clean up my deploy scripts namely `DockerCompose@0`.  What I am trying to implement the equivalent of

```
- task: DockerCompose@0
  displayName: 'Remove build options'
    inputs:
      action: 'Combine configuration'
      removeBuildOptions: true
```

So basically I was thinking of using `yq` which will parse the YAML file and remove the build options which are not applicable on the stack deployment.  However, I am not exactly sure how to do it.  Since I need to remove it from every service that MAY include it.

So given the following input

```yaml
services:
  def:
    build: ./def
    image: trajano/def
  ghi:
    image: trajano/ghi
version: '3.7'
```

I want to get

```yaml
services:
  def:
    image: trajano/def
  ghi:
    image: trajano/ghi
version: '3.7'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For newer yq versions ([see Docs](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/delete)):

```
yq eval 'del(services.[].build)' foo.yml
```

Comment: `yq eval 'del(.services.def.build)' foo.yml` worked for me

Comment: Yeah, for me to it worked with the period before `services` as in above comment:
`yq eval 'del(.services.def.build)' foo.yml`

Answer (score 0):

```
yq d foo.yml 'services.*.build'
```

To do this in Azure pipelines

```yaml
steps:
- bash: |
    URL="https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.26.2/docker-compose-Linux-x86_64"
    sudo curl -sL $URL -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
    sudo snap install yq
  displayName: Install additional software
- bash: |
    docker-compose config | yq d - 'services.*.build' > $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/docker-compose.yml
  displayName: Clean up docker-compose.yml
```